# Reload page React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make React refresh the page when I switch to it using `this.props.history.push`? I need to completely reload the page, is it possible to push some parameters?

```
 setTimeout(() => his.props.history.push('/'), 1000);
```

Comment: You can do forceupdate() i guess

Comment: It is recommended not to use at all.

Comment: Yes normally you should avoid it. Unless you can't achieve it by any other way